# How to combine multiple arrays from form submission (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, sqlsrv

I have a form that submits multiple entries, and needs to be able to combine those entries into a single SQL statement. When the Submit button is clicked, the "firstname", "lastname", etc. get put into their own arrays, so I have something like this:

```
$firstname = array(
'1' => john, 
'2' => mike,
'3' => pete
);

$lastname = array(
'1' => smith, 
'2' => jones,
'3' => ross
);
```

I want to combine these to have an output of

"John Smith, Mike Jones, Pete Ross" (maybe a third array?) so that I can make an SQLSRV Query like

```
"INSERT INTO database_table
(firstname, lastname)
Values  ($firstnames, $lastnames)"
```

Forgive my syntax, it's been a long day and I've been beating my head against the wall trying to figure this out (plus I'm a newb).

Comment: Why must they be in 1 query? Each row in the database should be it's own query, perhaps on a loop to be dynamic. You can loop bind parameters to your query so all of the inserts are executed at once. You should definitely be using prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find out how many value pairs you plan to insert and then generate the appropriate number. Here is a basic example (**please do not use this exactly as this leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection**):

```
$firstname = array(
    '1' => john, 
    '2' => mike,
    '3' => pete
);

$lastname = array(
    '1' => smith, 
    '2' => jones,
    '3' => ross
);

$query = '
    INSERT INTO database_table (firstname, lastname)
    VALUES 
';
$value_array = array();

foreach ($firstname as $index => $value) {
    $value_array[] = sprintf('("%s","%s")', $value, $lastname[$index]);
}

$query .= implode(', ', $value_array);

echo $query;
```

Example: https://eval.in/856592

What you should do is use something like above to generate strings for use with prepared statements such as:

```
foreach ($firstname as $index => $value) {
    $value_array[] = sprintf('(?, ?)');
}
```

Then bind the appropriate parameters after in another loop. This is far more secure.

Read more about prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Or even better: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you so much, being a newb, I've not messed with arrays indepthly, and haven't worked with the sprintf() at all. I should be able to get something going with this foundation you've laid out, thanks!